# Convert the doc,images and text files into pdf file in alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I want to convert the doc, xslx and other files to pdf in Alfresco. Currently I found this snippet to convert the doc, images and text files into pdf file by using rendition service.

**Here is my code:**

```
renditionDef = renditionService.createRenditionDefinition('cm:pdfRendition', 'reformat');
renditionDef.parameters["mime-type"] = "application/pdf";
```

I am not sure from where to start and where to add this snippet. Any help and guidance in this will be really beneficial to proceed in my work.

Comment: How are you planning to trigger the change? Automatically? Server side JS? WebScript? Other?

Comment: Any way will be fine. Either through repo or through share. Automatically will be better for the users.

Comment: https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/quick-print

Comment: I need to develop something like quick-print. Not sure how to do that. I have done my part in share.Though the print is not working for documents other than pdf.

Comment: If you want it done automatically, using a Rule on the folder is likely to be your best bet

Comment: Can you help me how this can be done?